# Google Docs Time-driven file permission change

Tags: file-permissions, google-docs-api, user-permissions, eventtrigger

I have a Google Doc that I want to change the user permissions for, based on the time of day. To be precise, I need it to be restricted from 9am - 12pm and 1pm to 6pm. At all other times I want anyone with the link to be able to comment on it.

Up until now I have been manually doing this every day, but I want it to be automatic. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference), and use [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to run functions from the script at specific times or time intervals.

You can change a file's sharing permissions, commenters, editors, etc. with the class [`File`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) from the [Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) to modify the Doc's commenters.